# Inequality to be solved for probability problem

Tags: inequality

How to solve the below inequality?

$$ \frac{r}{r+b} > \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}, \ \text{for } b > 0 $$

This type of mathematics I studied many years ago, but I cannot find a suitable primer to get started.

Comment: Cross-multiply and subtract to turn into an inequality of the form (something)${}>0$. Be careful with the signs of the denominators (must $r$ be positive as well?). Which variable do you want to solve for?

Comment: Its both actually. Red and black socks problem from https://mbapreponline.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/fifty_challenging_problems_in__2.pdf

Comment: R must be positive as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP also mentioned that $r>0$ in the comment section.

If $r+b-1>0$, then from $b>0$,

$$\begin{align*}
r-1 &< r+b-1\\
\frac{r-1}{r+b-1} &< \frac 11\\
\end{align*}$$

Either the LHS numerator is negative, so the given inequality is true; or the LHS numerator is non-negative, so by the [mediant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties), the following is always true:

$$\frac{r-1}{r+b-1} < \frac{r}{r+b}<\frac 11$$

So $r>1-b$ makes the given inequality always satisfied.

---

Otherwise, if $r+b-1<0$, then from $b>0$,

$$\begin{align*}
r-1 &< r+b-1 &(<0)\\
\frac{1-r}{1-(r+b)} &> \frac 11\\
\end{align*}$$

By the same mediant inequality, the following is always true:

$$
\frac{1-r}{1-(r+b)}>\frac 11 > \frac{r}{r+b}\\
\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}>\frac 11 > \frac{r}{r+b}
$$

This contradicts the given inequality, so $0<r<1-b$ are *not* solutions.

---

So with the given condition that $r>0$, $r>\max(1-b,0)$ is the solution.

Comment: I will look at in due course as am in transit. Thx.

Comment: Hard for me to follow. Getting old on this.

Comment: @thebluephantom This is based on mediants. For two fractions $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$ with non-negative numerators and positive denominators, their mediant $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is between them. For a random example unrelated to your question, since $$\frac47 < \frac{10}9,$$ their mediant is between them: $$\frac 47 < \frac{4+10}{7+9} < \frac{10}9.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{r}{r + b} - \frac{r - 1}{r + b - 1} > 0$$
$$\frac{r(r + b - 1) - (r-1)(r+b)}{(r + b - 1)(r + b)} > 0$$
$$\frac{(r^2 + rb - r) - (r^2+rb-r-b)}{(r + b - 1)(r + b)} > 0$$
$$\frac{b}{(r + b)(r + b - 1)} > 0$$
Since $b > 0$, $(r + b)(r + b - 1) > 0$ must hold, so $r \in (-\infty,-b) \cup(-b + 1, \infty)$. You can learn about solving quadratic inequalities [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/inequality-quadratic-solving.html).

Comment: I thank u but i need to see intermediate steps.

Comment: I don't know what else you want from this answer - combine the fractions to go to the second line, then use a sign chart to solve the inequality. Review whatever notes you have on solving rational inequalities.

Comment: @thebluephantom: There are all intermediate steps in answer. Don't you understand where 1st line comes from? Don'y you understand how 2nd line is obtained from 1st? Don't you understand how 3rd lines comes from 2nd? Don't you understand how final result follows from inequality in 3rd line?

Comment: It stands to reason I would not have asked the question. There was a time i did this at uni, but that is a long time ago. I asked a few grads here they could not do it either. So dont lecture me.

Comment: @thebluephantom which part do you not understand? I could elaborate on that.

Comment: @thebluephantom I have made some edits, see if it's clear now.

Comment: I will look later tonight as I am in transit.

Comment: So, I looked at link. That I remembered but I could not relate to the example I gave and the steps.